# rest client example in python version 2.7.1

Tags: python

Following is the piece of code I have written, but on executing this code nothing is happening. I mean no error nor a proper result is getting displayed. I can only see a blank `python shell`, where as other python programs running properly. I am using python `version 2.7.1`

API_call.py:

```
import requests
import json

class API_call:
    def GET_call(self):
        print 'Inside GET_Call method'
        response= requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
        if response.status_code==200:
            print 'URL ACTIVE'
            print (response.json)
        elif response.status_code!=200:
            print 'URL INACTIVE'
            print (response.content)
            print (response.json)


api_call= API_call()
api_call.GET_call
```

**Output:**

```
====================== RESTART: C:/Python27/API_call.py ======================
```

Comment: Put () after call.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function call `()`. Also, `if a == True: ... elif a != True: ...` is just doing exactly the same than `if a == True: ... else: ...` with worse perfomance. The condition is getting checked twice instead of once and it requires more code.

```
import requests
import json

class API_call:
    def GET_call(self):
        print 'Inside GET_Call method'
        response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print 'URL ACTIVE'
            print (response.json)
        else:
            print 'URL INACTIVE'
            print (response.content)
            print (response.json)


api_call = API_call()
api_call.GET_call()
```